# Java Android room alter table java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle

Tags: java, android, android-room

I want to add column to existing table I do this :

```
 static final Migration MIGRATION_33_35 = new Migration(33, 35) {
        @Override
        public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
            database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE 'Orders' " + " ADD COLUMN 'lats' REAL  ");

        }
    };
private static DbManager buildDatabaseInstance(Context context) {
    return Room.databaseBuilder(context,
            DbManager.class,
            DB_NAME)
            .addMigrations(MIGRATION_31_32,MIGRATION_33_35)//nazwa powinna byc 32_33
            .allowMainThreadQueries().build();
}
```

And I do not want to lose my data in which I have rows.
Now I have this :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle table
```